# running multiple services at one time in android

Tags: android, service

I am devloping an android application with multiple tabs. My tabs have the following.

1st tab - It shows archives for a magazine in a grid view. The intention is to when I tap a grid view Item, I would need to download a large file from a web site. For this I have created a service that has an ASYNC task that would download the file. I have shown the code.

```
 public class DownloadArchivesService extends BaseService {
private static final String TAG = "DownloadArchivesServices";
private static final String STOP = "stop_modificator";
public static final String ALREADY_RUNNING= "DownloadArchivesService_Already_Running";
public  static final String ARCHIVES_PERCENTAGE_PROGRESS ="Archives_Percentage_Progress";
public  static final String UPDATE_ARCHIVES_PROGRESS = "Update_Archives_Progress";

 @Override
public void onCreate() {
            getPreferences().edit().putBoolean(ALREADY_RUNNING,   true).commit();
    application = (JfwApplication)this.getApplicationContext();
    context = this;
    session = application.getSession();
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    magazineManager = new MagazineManager(this);

    //magazine = new Magazine(fileName, fileName, "", "", this);


    new AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>() {

    NumberFormat formater = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //  I do my download here       }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... p) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            return;
        }
        //I udpate my progress bar here     }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Intent intentInvalidate = new Intent(ArchivesActivity.GRID_INVALIDATE);
        sendBroadcast(intentInvalidate);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}.execute();

super.onCreate();


}
```

When I navigate to my second tab, I would need to download a few photos from the website and display it on the screen. I have written a service similar to the above - DownloadImagesService.

But the problem is when the above mentioned DownloadArchivesService is running,(i.e., when I had 
 tapped a grid view item to invoke the DownloadArchivesService) and navigate to the second tab to download the photos,The DownloadImageService(The service to download photos) is not invoked and it waits till the DownloadArchivesService is completed. This would make the user to wait for sometime before the first service completes. I understand that the services would run in main thread and one service would need to wait for an already executing service to execute.
Is there a way around to run different services(or background tasks) concurrently without waiting for a previously excecuting services.

I did go through various documents on the Services, Intent services and threads. But I could not undertand this particular thing on how andorid handles concurrent services.

I would greatly appreciate any help on this. Please let me know If My explanation is not clear.

Thanks.

Comment: is one of your services inheriting from the other? Or both from the same Parent Class? Did you write the BaseService class yourself or does it come with android? Not sure atm. If so check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150430/android-multiple-services-dont-run-as-expected?rq=1

Comment: @Androidika,Both the services inherit the class BaseService.This is not an android class

Comment: @androidika,. I have seen the post you mentioned. I will try to make the services independent. Thanks for your help. That was very quick. In fact I am writing my application, only thru the clarity that all the posts have given me. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. **Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.**

If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

I would suggest you to use executor for this purpose

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Comment: I tried executing executeOnExecutor and it worked fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

From Android 4.0+ `AsyncTask` are given a single thread of execution. So 2nd `AsyncTask` will run after the completion of first.

See [Multiple Async Task not running in android 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742074/multiple-async-task-not-running-in-android-4-1) for how to handle them.

Comment: ,Thanks for your reply. Do you think, even if the Async tasks run as a part of different service, the second would run after the first?